# R does not allow installing packages

Tags: r, install.packages

How can I solve the following message:

Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-02-01/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-02-01/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

I can´t install packages as 'imputeTS', 'corrplot', ...

I have tried install packages from local files, but some packages have several dependencies and this option can be very tedious

I have tried uninstall and reinstall R and RStudio, but the problem persist.

Comment: Try changing your CRAN repo.

Comment: [MRAN has been retired](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/microsoft-r-application-network-retirement/ba-p/3707161). Find a new repo, perhaps from https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html or you can use Posit's [packagemanager](https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/) for increased possibility of having binary packages available for your system.